# How to translate “Who’s in?”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, slang, informal

I’d like a colloquial translation of

> Who’s in?

a bit like *Wer kommt?* but less formal.

Comment: Context would really help...

Comment: Even more colloquial (i.e. verbal) and also with contraction: **Wer’s dabei?**

Comment: "Wer's dabei?" Doesn't make too much sense too me. It would be a abbreviation for "Wer is dabei?" which would be a dialect form of "Wer ist dabei?"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First thoughts would be:

> Wer ist dabei?
>   Wer macht mit?
>   Wer geht / kommt mit? (depending on context)

Comment: First option is heard most in my group’s social room ;)

Comment: @Jan Guess why I put this in first position ;-)